# Store the static json string into an string

Tags: json, nsstring, apex-code

I tried to store the json string in this below manner

```
NSString * str =@"{"CategoryID":1,"ItemCount":1,"level":1,"Name":"Boots","Description":"Boots descrition","childs":[{"CategoryID":2,"ItemCount":1,"level":2,"Name":"Cold Water","Description":"Cold Water Description","childs":[]}]}]";
```

I got an error message.I know it is a very small solution.
And i tried so many NSString methods but i did n't get the solution.
How will i store this string ?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: "I got an error message". What was that ?

Comment: The error is expected ';'at the end of the declaration

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got the solution for my question

we need to pass the string in the below way.

```
 NSString*str=@{\"CategoryID\":1,\"ItemCount\":1,\"level\":1,\"Name\":\"Boots\",\"Description":\"Boots descrition\",\"childs\"[{\"CategoryID\":2,\"ItemCount\":1,\"level\":2,\"Name\":\"Cold Water\",\"Description\":\"Cold Water Description\",\"childs\":[]}]}];
```